# How to use app namespace in Style

Tags: android

I was doing something like this in layout file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@color/colorPrimary">
```

But i want to use this style at multiple place so i tried to move it in style.xml file

```
  <style name="FindInstituteInputTextViewStyle" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="app:hintTextAppearence">colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

But now this give me following exceptions.

```
Error:(2376, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:hintTextAppearence'.
```

I also tried placing app namespace attr in  < resource >
 tag inside style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
```

But again it didn't work for me. Please help me and sorry if i am doing some silly mistake

Answer (score 3):

```
<style name="FindInstituteInputTextViewStyle" >
    ... ...
    <item name="hintTextAppearence">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not create own tag, so trying to use such will cause error as you see it. Own styles you created are used by reference with existing tags, no namespace needed. i.e.:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/FindInstituteInputTextViewStyle" /
```

See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Also this line:

```
<item name="app:hintTextAppearence">colorPrimary</item>
```

does not seem to refer to color properly, so it should not even compile.